# How to fill the Email address field within https://www.nike.com/register using Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I'm trying to use selenium to fill out the registration form on the nike website here: https://www.nike.com/register but it can't find the elements using the xpath or the id.

Here's what I have tried so far:

```
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--incognito")
chrome_options.add_argument("start-maximized")
driver=webdriver.Chrome('/Users/cameron/Desktop/untitled folder/chromedriver')

driver.get('https://www.nike.com/gb/membership')
main_window = driver.current_window_handle
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="69dcecd3-722e-42c0-aa82-358c4160ae8d"]/div/div/div[2]/a').click()

WebDriverWait(driver, 5)
driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[2]/div[3]/div[4]/form/div[1]/input').click()
```

it works fine when navigating the website but it can't find the elements when trying to fill the signup form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To send a *character sequence* to the *Email address* field you have to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808) for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  driver.get('https://www.nike.com/gb/membership')
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a[aria-label='Join Us'][href='https://www.nike.com/register']"))).click()
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[name='emailAddress']"))).send_keys("Cameroon08@stackoverflow.com")
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  driver.get('https://www.chegg.com/auth?action=login&redirect=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.chegg.com%2F')
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[@aria-label='Join Us' and @href='https://www.nike.com/register']"))).click()
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@name='emailAddress']"))).send_keys("Cameroon08@stackoverflow.com")
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```
- Browser Snapshot:

[image: nike_register]

Comment: Thank you, I used the CSS selector method and it worked perfectly

Comment: I will do, how do you get the CSS selectors, I can't seem to get the correct selectors for the other elements. The password field for example doesn't work using the CSS selector from chrome